# Get user agent screen size and add it in MySQL with javascript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, user-agent, screen-size

I have a script that gets a user's browser screen size using JavaScript and adds the variablse to MySQL with PHP.

I have a problem with my script, because the JavaScript works on user's side and PHP works on server side.

I do it like in my script example, but in MySQL adding line with all javascript code, not with user browser screen size.  Please help me to solve my problem. Thank you.

P.S. Script working in "shadow".

```
<?php 

$width = "<script>document.write(screen.width);</script>";
$height = "<script>document.write(screen.height);</script>";
$resolution = $width.' x '.$height;

//-- Create connection
$conishua = new mysqli($sv_name, $ur_name, $multipass, $db_name);
$conishua->set_charset('utf8');

//-- Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){echo "Failed to connect to DB: " . mysqli_connect_error();}

//-- Open DB a check if exist
$base_search = $conishua->query("SELECT id FROM `db_name` LIMIT 1");

#IF DB NOT EXIST - CREATE IT AND DO A QUERY
if ($base_search === FALSE) {

    //-- Create not existed DB
    $user_ip_table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db_name` (
    `id` int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    `ip` tinytext NOT NULL,
    `agent` tinytext NOT NULL,
    `date` tinytext NOT NULL,
    `time` tinytext NOT NULL,
    `resolution` tinytext NOT NULL)AUTO_INCREMENT=146789 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;";

        //-- Do a query for new user ip if DB exist
        if ($conishua->query($user_ip_table) === TRUE && !$BOT) {

            $newUser = "INSERT INTO `db_name` (ip, agent, date, time, resolution) values ('$ip', '$agent', '$date', '$time', '$resolution')";
            $rs = $conishua->query($newUser);

        }


} ?>
```

In MySql output just like this 
    `<script> document.write(screen.width); </ script>` instead 1388 x 768 or else.

Please help modify my script.

Comment: What's the problem? Why not transfer the resolution from the client to the backend? Obviously, your PHP server has no screen

Comment: @NicoHaase... I don't know how to do it (

Comment: You're confusing things that happen on the client versus things that happen on the server. You'll probably want to use Ajax to send the dimensions to your PHP script.

Comment: @Dave.. maybe, but i don't know how to do it..

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php) should get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: You need to post the client side data to the server side. You don't need a form to do it but the principals are the same. You simply can not get something running in JavaScript back to PHP without sending it somehow.

Comment: @Dave.. maybe you can give an example for me?

Comment: @КатеринаМусакина....

Nice solution, i like it

$base_search = $conishua->query("SELECT id FROM `db_name` LIMIT 1");

Comment: @WebSon... thank you very much